# Error Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded when both IIS and Wamp are running

Tags: php, mysql, iis, wamp

I have IIS and WAMP both install and I am in a situation where I would need both to run simultaneously. The problem is if they both run whenever I want to access a php application using IIS I am getting error `Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded` How can I run the application from IIS while Wamp is running ? I need the data I need is on wamp mysql.

Comment: on which port your wamp server is running? what is the site binding for the wamp and iis? This warning happens when there is a PHP extension loaded more than once. To fix this problem, you must edit your php.ini (or extensions.ini) file and comment-out the extensions that are already compiled-in.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: I run wamp server on 81 and IIS on 80 to escape the problem I run IIS before running wamp.

Comment: I request you to post a helpful suggestion as an answer and mark that. it will help other people who face a similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I run wamp server on 81 and IIS on 80 to escape the problem I run IIS before running wamp.